# Add elements to a HashMap containing an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

This simple method is supposed to add elements to a HashMap. The elements are read from a txt file, I have tested that and everything regarding that area is working just fine. The issue comes when I print the values that are in the Map.Therefore, I think there might be some issue when adding them.

The content of the txt file is

```
SW: (scores, 90); (scores, 91); (scores, 92);
```

Where the Permissions is "SW" and the Attributes are "(scores, 90)... (scores, 92)". These are the elements used in the following methods.

```
public Map<Permissions, ArrayList<Attributes>> paMap; 

public void addMap(Permissions per, Attributes att) {
    if(paMap.containsKey(per)) {
        paMap.get(per).add(att);            
    }
    else{
        ArrayList<Attributes> attList = new ArrayList<Attributes>();
        attList.add(att);
        paMap.put(per, attList);
    }
}

 //Attributes contain variables (Scores) and values(90-93), that is just for printing

public void printMap() {
    ArrayList<Attributes> list;

    for(Permissions p: paMap.keySet()) {
        list = paMap.get(p);
        System.out.print(p.name + ": ");

        for(Attributes l: list) {
            System.out.print("<" + l.variable +", " + l.value + ">; ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

When I print the Map I expect to get exactly the same thing that is in the txt file, but instead I get

SW: (scores, 92); (scores, 92); (scores, 92)

Even if I remove the `paMap.get(per).add(att)` line from the addMap method I end up getting SW: (scores, 92);

Also, I have tested if the for loop is being called properly and it is.

Therefore, I am confused on how the attributes on the ArrayList are getting updated and what would be the right way of doing it. Do you see any error in the way I am adding or printing the values?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Show us how you read the txt file call the `addMap(...)` method.

Comment: @Luis Claramunt Can you also add your code for `Permissions` class? As mentioned in the answer - it's important to make `Permissions` immutable and define `equals and hashCode` properly.

Comment: Beware using mutable objects as map keys

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how looks like read method but seems like You are adding all the time the same attribute, so maybe in read function You are not create new attribute but using the same object all the time and just call sets on this, so in the array lsit at the end is the same object added three times

btw:
also method addmap can be replaced by:

```
paMap.computeIfAbsent(per,x->new ArrayList<Attributes>()).add(att);
```

If You are using java8 and above ;)

Comment: `x -> new ArrayList<>()` should be enough, the diamond operator can be safely used here.

Comment: The `computeIfAbsent()` advice was great! It indeed did the same as the entire `addMap` method. Unfortunately, it did exactly the same so it is still printing the wrong output. Therefore, I think the error must be somewhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

- use interfaces in the `Map` declaration:

```
public Map<Permissions, List<Attributes>> paMap;
```

- in order to be used as key in the `Map` ensure `Permissions` is
  immutable and has `equals` and `hashCode` properly defined

So, assuming `Permissions` has only 1 String field, it should look something like this:

```
public final class Permissions {
  private final String permission;
  public Permissions(String permission) {
    this.permission = permission;
  }
  public String getPermission() {
    return this.permission;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Permissions that= (Permissions ) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.permission, that.permission);
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.permission);
  }
}
```

- Try another implementation of `printMap` method. For example, with Java
  8:

```
  private void printMap() {
    paMap.entrySet().stream().map(this::format).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
  private String format(Map.Entry<Permissions, List<Attributes>> entry) {
    String key = formatPermissions(entry.getKey());
    String value = formatAttributes(entry.getValue());
    return String.format("%s: %s", key, value);
  }
  private String formatPermissions(Permissions permissions) {
    return permissions.name;
  }
  private String formatAttributes(List<Attributes> attributes) {
    return attributes.stream()
            .map(attr -> String.format("(%s, %s)", attr.variable, attr.value))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look more into using immutable objects as keys. Also, the for loop inside the `addMap` is not broken. It is one of the first things I tested and it only reaches the else statements for the first time the `addMap` function is called.